# extjs listview and paging

Tags: extjs

can listview (ExtJS 3.x) component support paging?
I could not find any examples on how to use paging on listview, any pointers?
thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component itself doesn't support paging natively but since it's fairly easy to extend extjs component you should be able to make our own, I advice you to take a look at the grid paging toolbar it will give you a start.

I think the toolbar is taking some event on the store and adding start and limit params so it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt that to a listview.

Comment: Thanks, for now I'll be just switching to Grid then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?81320-listview-and-paging

"A PagingToolbar is not associated with a component, it only needs to knows the store.

ListView doesn't have a bbar property, so you should put the ListView inside a Panel with layout:'fit' and set the bbar property of the Panel to the PagingToolbar instance."

Just tried it myself and it works perfectly. Create a panel which holds the listView, set the PagingToolbar to the bbar property.